# Email body empty in JUnit Test on local Google Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email, testing, junit

I'm using GAE API 1.7.3 on Mac OS X with JDK 7_10 and the GAE Maven Plugin.

My test is more or less copied from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Sending_Email_Messages):

```java
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@example.com", "Example.com Admin"));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("user@example.com", "Mr. User"));
    msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
    msg.setText(".....");
    Transport.send(msg);
```

The output is:

```
Dez 21, 2012 12:24:24 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO: MailService.send
Dez 21, 2012 12:24:24 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   From: "Example.com Admin" <admin@example.com>
Dez 21, 2012 12:24:24 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   To: "Mr. User" <user@example.com>
Dez 21, 2012 12:24:24 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Reply-to: "Example.com Admin" <admin@example.com>
Dez 21, 2012 12:24:24 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Subject: Your Example.com account has been activated
Dez 21, 2012 12:24:24 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Body:
Dez 21, 2012 12:24:24 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:     Content-type: text/plain
Dez 21, 2012 12:24:24 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:     Data length: 5
```

The unit test is initialized using:

```java
protected LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalMailServiceTestConfig());
```

What's really strange is, that the "Body" is empty, but the "Data length" is 5 (corresponding to the ".....").

Is this normal or what am I doing wrong here?

**[Update]** It is the same thing, if I use the low-level API:

```java
    MailService service = MailServiceFactory.getMailService();
    service.send(new MailService.Message(from, to, subject, text));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you called `setLogMailBody(true)` on the `LocalMailServiceTestConfig`?